# Disable Leaflet draw toolbar when user creates a shape and enable it when the shape is deleted

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I would like to prevent a user from creating more than one shape on the map. For example if the user creates a polygon, then all shape icons on the toolbar should be disabled. When the user deletes the previously created shape, then icons on the toolbar should get enabled.

How can I do this? I tried removing the toolbar on the draw:created event and adding a new toolbar on draw:deleted event but it lead to errors (see attached screenshot).

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Leaflet enables us to remove and add the toolbars with `remove()` and `addTo()` methods.

What you need to do is to create two toolbars. One is a default `L.Control.Draw` and the other one is without the 'draw' component:

```
self.drawControlFull = new L.Control.Draw();

self.drawControlEdit = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: editableLayers,
    edit: false
  },
  draw: false
});

map.addControl(drawControlFull);
```

Then you just listen to the `draw:created` and `draw:deleted` events and you add/remove them as needed:

```
map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

    self.drawControlFull.remove();
    self.drawControlEdit.addTo(map);

  editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});

map.on('draw:deleted', function (e) {
    self.drawControlEdit.remove();
    self.drawControlFull.addTo(map);
});
```

This solution maybe doesn't cover all the use cases but it's just an example. I have also created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mallack/3f5jka5s/4/) for this so you can see how it works.

Comment: I had tried this approach earlier. But I was getting the error shown in the attached screenshot. (I've updated the question)

Comment: Can you maybe create a jsFiddle and reproduce your error (try to update mine)? My solution works with the latest version of leaflet and leaflet-draw. Maybe you are using an older version. If this is the case you need to change couple of things but it's similar.

Comment: Here's how you can duplicate it in your code. Create a shape. Then click on edit -->you get an error. Then click on cancel -->you get another error. (Use chrome debugger)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same error as the one you are having and also in the question you didn't mention editing of the drawn layer. As I've said this is just an example that covers add/delete case. You would need to have other event listeners to cover all cases.

Comment: Ok! Lets take editing shapes out of the picture. Can you help me out then?

Comment: I have edited the jsFiddle and now it hides the 'edit' control. You can now add and delete only one layer without any exceptions. If you can reproduce the same error in a live working example you have logged in the console, I will check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122812/discussion-between-marko-letic-and-codejunkie).